# How to perform tag combinational search?

Tags: mysql, database, search, schema, keyword-search

I have 4 MySQL tables like this;

**Table1**

```
========================
id1  |   brand   |  tags
-----+-----------+------
111  | mercedes  | xx
-----+-----------+------
222  | mercedes  | yy
-----+-----------+------
333  | ford      | xx,yy
-----+-----------+------
444  | audi      | yy,zz
-----+-----------+------
555  | jaguar    | xx,yy,zz
========================
```

**Table2**

```
========================
id2  |  model    |  id1
-----+-----------+------
aaa  | s class   | 111
-----+-----------+------
bbb  | figo      | 333
-----+-----------+------
ccc  | a6        | 444
-----+-----------+------
ddd  | xf        | 555
-----+-----------+------
eee  | a4        | 444
========================
```

**Table3**

```
============
id1  |  id3
-----+------
111  | xx
-----+------
222  | yy
-----+------
333  | xx
-----+------
333  | yy
-----+------
444  | yy
-----+------
444  | zz
-----+------
555  | xx
-----+------
555  | yy
-----+------
555  | zz
============
```

**Table4**

```
==================
id3  |  tagdetails
-----+------------
xx   | description
-----+------------
yy   | description
-----+------------
zz   | description
==================
```

I am doing direct search using brands and reverse searching using tags. When user search for brands, it give direct result. But when user search using tags (xx, yy, etc.), I want to display the combinations first. I mean, if user search for xx, then I want to display `xx`, `xx,yy`, `xx,yy,zz`, and like that. User may pich an option from this, which will display the brand.

I am using PHP+MySQL. How can I achieve this? Do I need to change the schema or need any additional tables?

Answer (score 0):

use MySQL `FIND_IN_SET`

```
Select * From Table1 WHERE FIND_IN_SET('xx',tags)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `like` for text value...

```
SELECT  id1 ,brand,tags FROM Table1 WHERE tags LIKE '%xx%'
```

OUTPUT:

```
========================
id1  |   brand   |  tags
-----+-----------+------
111  | mercedes  | xx
-----+-----------+------
333  | ford      | xx,yy
-----+-----------+------
444  | audi      | yy,zz
-----+-----------+------
555  | jaguar    | xx,yy,zz
========================
```

Comment: what about search keyword `zz,xx` ??

Comment: No result . and Solution is to make a dynamic query like `WHERE tags like '%zz%' and '%xx%' and so on` you can do this in php easily other wise you need to change table `schema`

Comment: and the problem is that for every query, we need to go through all records in table 1.. bang.. ;)

Comment: you have to no choice for this schema.